# Getting current user's cart in json on front end?

Tags: b2b-commerce, demandware

I'm trying to design a widget for user on https://www.michaels.com/ which is a demandware site. And I do see an API that would in theory allow me to do this described here: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2Fsfrajsdoc%2Fjs%2Fserver%2FCart.html as `Cart-Get`.

However, when trying to fetch it from the site via frontend like so:

```
fetch("https://www.michaels.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-MichaelsUS-Site/default/Cart-Get").then(res => res.json())
```

I'm sent to an error page instead of receiving cart json. I have same widget implemented on http://uniqlo.com/ as its also a demandware store. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first question here is, are you on the development team on the Demandware store?

If not, there might be some customizations made to that endpoint that no longer match up with the original SFRA.

Looking at the other endpoints, I do not recognize any standard SFRA controllers. This means this site has been heavily customized and may not even use SFRA (It could be based on SiteGenesis).

Comment: Well, development of the site completed years ago by an agency and the agency for this client does have allocated hours for me but the answer is that I am not on that team tho I do have limited access to them.

What should I ask them or point them to?

Comment: I would point them to the code of SFRA and ask them to emulate the JSON response.